# The 'profile_picture' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, attributes

I am trying to create access my profile but one of my models attributes (profile_picture) is empty and it's causing my profile page to crash. I have set `blank=True`, and it was working earlier but it has stopped working since and i can't figure out why. If I go to the django admin and manually add a profile then I can visit my profile again and everything works. I guess my question is why can't I view my profile even if the profile_pic attribute is empty? Shouldn't `blank=True` take care of that?

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def edit_user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        form = EditUserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_user_profile.html', args)
```

Profile.html

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h2>{{ user }}</h2>
  <br>

  <p>Name: {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
  <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}" width="240px">
  <p></p>
  <p>Motto: {{ user.userprofile.description }}</p>
  <p>Youtube: <a href="{{ user.userprofile.website }}">{{ user.userprofile.website }}</a></p>
  <p>About Me: {{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
  <p>Phone Number: {{ user.userprofile.phone }}</p>


  <a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}">Edit Profile</a><br>


<!-- if profile is updated succesfully -->
 {% if messages %}
 {% for message in messages %}

 <br><br>{{ message }}

 {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

</div>
```

Again, if I go the Django admin and manually upload a photo I can access my profile but by default it won't work without an image.

Any insight is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the code `{{ user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}` in template.

It always try to find picture's url even if your profile_picture is none.

Just add `if/else` in template, or add method if you have default image.

ie. if/else in template

```
  {% if user.userprofile.profile_picture %}
      <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}" width="240px">
  {% else %}
      <img src="{% static 'your_default_img_path' %}" width="240px">
  {% endif %}
```

Or use method for picture

```
# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_profile_picture(self):
        if self.profile_picture
            return profile_picture_url
        else:
            return 'your_default_img_url_path'
```

Comment: Okay so I added the if/else template and the error has gone. How do I set the default template? At the moment I just have a directory for profile uploads. Where would I create this static default image path? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean static default image path? You mean `upload_to`?

Comment: Oh it's just from static for example. If you want to add default image, add it to your static dir and call it use `{% static 'your_path/to/img' %}`

Comment: Sorry it was a dumb question. Figured it out and selected your answer as best. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in views.py

```
form = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              city = form.cleaned_data['city']
              description = form.cleaned_data['description']
              profile_picture = form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
              website = form.cleaned_data['website']
              phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
              EditUser= UserProfile(city =city,
                                   description=description,
                                   profile_picture =profile_picture,
                                   website =website,
                                   phone =phone,
                                   user_id=request.user)
              EditUser.save()
              return redirect('/accounts/profile')

          else:
              form = EditUserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
              args = {'form': form}
              return render(request, 'accounts/edit_user_profile.html', args)
```